# Uncaught Error: Class 'Slim\Factory\AppFactory' not found in in Slim Framework

Tags: composer-php, slim

I have a problem when I install Slim Framework using Composer. First, I'm using this code:

```
composer create-project slim/slim-skeleton aplikasi-slim -vvv
```

After I start the slim using `composer start` and then open localhost:8080, it shows "Hello World".

Then I get an issue when I using this code:

```
composer require slim/slim "^3.0"
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Slim\Factory\AppFactory' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\aplikasi-slim\public\index.php:36 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\aplikasi-slim\public\index.php on line 36**

I've been creating a new file index.php into the directory like this:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\app;

$app-> get('/' function(){
echo "Heloow word";
});

$app->run();
```

and I still get an error. Can you help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Why you want to use the old version of slim?

Comment: `composer create-project slim/slim-skeleton` installs Slim v4, and that skeleton project is using that specific version, which has a `Slim\Factory\AppFactory` class. But `composer require slim/slim "^3.0"` installs Slim v3, which does not include that specific class.

Comment: You should not mix Slim 4 with Slim 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have typo on:

```
$app = new \Slim\app;
```

Should be

```
$app = new \Slim\App;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one little problem. If you go to the official website and look for it you will find two composer requirement. The same thing happened with me a while back. So I had to install them both and now they are working. If you follow the exact user guide this won't happen.
https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/start/installation.html
This link is for v4. But I can assure you this will work for this too. Try it.